# Prevent alias expansion when alias is passed as an argument

Tags: alias

I have two aliases:

```bash
alias rm='python my/rm/script.py '
alias docker='sudo docker '
```

The problem is that when running the statement `$ docker rm ARGS` the keyword `rm` is being expanded as alias and docker complains that `'python' is not a docker command.`

I looked for a couple of solutions. One solution is to use `command` keyword. Another is to use `shopt` to toggle alias expansion. I'm unable to put them to good use.

Both of these are not working out for me:

```bash
alias docker='shopt -u expand_aliases; sudo docker '
alias docker='command sudo docker '
```

Unalias works:

```bash
alias docker='unalias rm; sudo docker '
```

The problem with unalias is that after a while I'm gonna forget that my rm alias is no longer in place in a running shell environment wherever my docker commands have been executed. As a result me using `rm` on a file would instantly erase it, in contrast to my python script which acts as a safetynet and moves to-be-deleted files in Trash. I want to avoid getting into this situation where I mistakenly end-up using GNU rm command and not my rm alias, and that's why I don't want to use unalias.

Another solution is to let go of docker alias. The downside is that I'd have to write `sudo` keyword for every useful docker command I want to execute. That is a chore which I was avoiding using the alias for docker.

One more solution is to escape rm keyword like this:

```
docker \rm ARGS
```

This works. But I'm hoping for a fire-and-forget solution here so that I can execute my docker commands naturally without concerning about anything else.

Given the above constraints, how do I use alias for both rm and docker but prevent `rm` keyword being expanded as alias in docker commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your `rm` alias is expanded when used after your `docker` alias is because the definition of the `docker` alias includes a space at the end.  Putting a space at the end of the alias definition is *the* way to ask the shell to apply alias expansion to the next word.

Solution: Define your `docker` alias without a space at the end.  You may also want to remove the space from the end of your other aliases.

You could probably also get rid of your `docker` alias entirely by adding your user to the `docker` group, but that's an administrational decision that you take locally.